# How can my Ruby "Time.now" timings be so low when my "ping" timings are so high?

Tags: windows, ruby, time, networking, ping

I'm using MongoDB for the first time and trying to time its performance.   I'm running ruby on a VirtualBox Ubuntu 9.10 guest with a Windows 7 64-bit host.   MongoDB is on a remote host, not on my lan buit somewhere in the internet cloud.

Here's my code:

```
time1 = Time.now
rows = coll.find(some_criteria)
puts ((Time.now - time1) * 1000).to_s
```

The problem is, the time is so small, I don't believe what I'm seeing.  I'm seeing times around 50, 100, 200 **MICRO**seconds, while ping times between my computer and the remote mongo computer are around 40 **MILLI**seconds.    Am I misunderstanding the units?  How can my timings be so low when the ping is so high?

Comment: You need to fix your formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You could start a packet sniffer, start irb, and then issue some test commands one line at a time, but you already seem to have accurately analyzed its dynamic behavior.

So, I suppose you got `coll` with something like `coll = db.collection_names`? And I suppose `coll` must be an *Enumerable*?

If so, nothing really needs to happen in that call except the return of an object with an `each` method. Perhaps nothing actually does happen until you ask for something *from* the *Enumerable*.

You might try:

```
time1 = Time.now
rows = coll.find(some_criteria)
o = rows.first
puts ((Time.now - time1) * 1000).to_s
```

This won't necessarily take any longer. It's possible that the work was done when `db.collection_names` was called. The irb test, from the top, might shed some light on the issue...

Comment: I'm ssh'ed into the remote host to, watching MongoDB's verbose output, and from that output I *KNOW* there is a network round trip going on.    So, I'm just baffled by the difference in ping time versus the time that ruby measures.

Comment: It may simply return an `Enumerable` AND also start a socket op for which it doesn't need a synchronous result. This would launch a round trip but also return immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: this line isn't doing what you expect:

```
rows = coll.find(some_criteria)
```

specifically, it's not communicating with the server.